# How am I suppposed to handle the BOM while text processing using sys.stdin in Python 3?

Tags: python, utf-8, text-processing, byte-order-mark

*Note: The [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898294/convert-utf-8-with-bom-to-utf-8-with-no-bom-in-python) concerns an older version of Python and this question has already generated unique answers.*

I have been working on a script to process [Project Gutenberg Texts](https://gutenberg.org) texts into an internal file format for an application I am developing. In the script I process chapter headings with the `re` module. This works very well except in one case: the first line. My regex will always fail on the first Chapter marker at the first line if it includes the ^ caret to require the regex match to be at the beginning of the line because the BOM is consumed as the first character. (Example regex: `^Chapter`).

What I've discovered is that if I do not include the caret, it won't fail on the first line, and then `<feff>` is included in the heading after I've processed it. An example:

```
<h1><feff>Chapter I</h1>
```

The advice according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972362/why-is-my-bash-script-adding-feff-to-the-beginning-of-files) (from which I learned of the BOM) is to fix your script to not consume/corrupt the BOM. [Other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456380/utf-8-html-and-css-files-with-bom-and-how-to-remove-the-bom-with-python) talk about decoding the file with a codec but discuss errors I never encounter and do not discuss the syntax for opening a file with the template decoder.

To be clear:

I generally use pipelines of the following format:

```
cat -s <filename> | <other scripts> | python <scriptname> [options] > <outfile>
```

And I am opening the file with the following syntax:

```
import sys

fin = sys.stdin

if '-i' in sys.argv: # For command line option "-i <infile>"
    fin = open(sys.argv[sys.argv.index('-i') + 1], 'rt')

for line in fin:
    ...Processing here...
```

**My question is what is the proper way to handle this? Do I remove the BOM before processing the text? If so, how? Or do I use a decoder on the file before processing it (I am reading from stdin, so *how* would I accomplish this?)**

The files are stored in UTF-8 encoding with DOS endings (`\r\n`). I convert them in vim to UNIX file format before processing using `set ff=unix` (I have to do several manual pre-processing tasks before running the script).

Comment: Hmm, `fin = sys.argv[sys.argv.index('-i') + 1]` should give you a filename in `fin`. It should then be opened with an `open` call that you have not shown and that is the place where you could declare that you want to filter the BOM out. Could you please show your `open` instruction?

Comment: @Serge I apologize. I typed it from memory and forgot to include the open. However, I mostly use `sys.stdin` because I've been using it in pipelines. I would especially like to know how to declare it with `sys.stdin`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UTF-8 with BOM to UTF-8 with no BOM in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898294/convert-utf-8-with-bom-to-utf-8-with-no-bom-in-python)

Comment: Python 3 should transparently normalize the line endings with text files (Python 2 had `'Ur' ` for opening a file for reading with line-ending normalization) . The gist of the proposed duplicate is to use the `utf-8-sig` encoding when opening the file to transparently ignore the BOM, too.

Comment: If you are preprocessing the files anyway, it might be the easiest to chop it off in that process. Check the first character and remove it if it is the "zero-width non-breaking space".

Comment: @tripleee: Unfortunately, when I process a DOS-ending line `re.search('^$')` fails to match blank lines.

Comment: @lenz: How would I go about checking if it is the "zero-width non-breaking space"??

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240387/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file

Comment: I think tripleee's link should help you; it really depends on the tool how to spell a specific Unicode character.

Comment: To note for future readers: tripleee's link is excellent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a complement to the existing answer, it is possible to filter the UTF8 BOM from stdin with the codecs module. Simply you must use `sys.stdin.buffer` to access the underlying byte stream and decode it with a `StreamReader`

```
import sys
import codecs

# trick to process sys.stdin with a custom encoding
fin = codecs.getreader('utf_8_sig')(sys.stdin.buffer, errors='replace')


if '-i' in sys.argv: # For command line option "-i <infile>"
    fin = open(sys.argv[sys.argv.index('-i') + 1], 'rt',
               encoding='utf_8_sig', errors='replace')

for line in fin:
    ...Processing here...
```

Comment: This actually seems to be the most elegant solution as it (seems to me) to be more portable than the other solutions. How will it handle non-utf-8 encoded scripts? Will it choke?

Comment: My comment seems to be due to a misunderstanding of BOMs and character encoding. After perusing [this Unix.SE discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62721/discussion-on-answer-by-stephane-chazelas-how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8) as well as [this quora question](https://www.quora.com/How-common-is-UTF-16BE-or-even-UTF-32-for-text-files-e-g-XML-or-JSON-yes-I-JSON-only-allows-UTF-8) I have come to the conclusion that I will probably never need to worry about the BOM except to remove it and therefore take this answer as the final, most elegant and portable solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, `stdin` *should* be auto-decoded properly, but if it's not working for you (and for Python 2) you need to specify [PythonIOEncoding](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) before invoking your script like

```
PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8-SIG" python <scriptname> [options] > <outfile>
```

Notice that this setting also makes `stdout` working with `UTF-8-SIG`, so your `<outfile>` will maintain the original encoding.

For your `-i` parameter, just do `open(path, 'rt', encoding="UTF-8-SIG")`

Comment: Can I just export an environment variable or does your solution require `PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8-SIG"` to be declared while I'm running the script?

Comment: Yes, declaring it as an environment variable should affect all python scripts

Comment: If you set it earlier in the script, it will remain set for the duration of the script (unless you explicitly unset or change it, of course). You need to `export` it so it's visible to subprocesses such as Python.

Comment: @tripleee: When you say "set it earlier in the script" is the script you are referring to my python script of my pipeline-command? I am curious because if I can just write this into my python script toward the top that might be the simplest solution.

Comment: The shell script containing the pipeline. If the Python script is simple you can embed it in the shell script but I would probably look into doing the preprocessing in Python too instead.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to import `codecs` or anything to deal with this. As lenz suggested in comments just check for the BOM and throw it out.

```
for line in input:
    if line[0] == "\ufeff":
        line = line[1:] # trim the BOM away

    # the rest of your code goes here as usual
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.9 default encoding for standard input seems to be `utf-8`, at least on Linux:

```
In [2]: import sys
In [3]: sys.stdin
Out[3]: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>
```

`sys.stdin` has the method `reconfigure()`:

```
sys.stdin.reconfigure("utf-8-sig")
```

which should be called before any attempt of reading the standard input. This will decode the BOM, which will no longer appear when reading `sys.stdin`.